# When is it useful to create a new reference to an object instead of copying the object?

Tags: python

It's often necessary to copy an object using `b = copy(a)` or `b = deepcopy(a)` instead of creating a new reference to the original object using `b = a`.  Otherwise, modifying `b` could result in unintentional modifications to `a` and vice versa.

However, I'm curious about when `b = a` is useful.  Below are some examples I can think of.  What else am I missing?

1. **Immutable Objects:** `b = a` is useful if you cannot modify the object to which `a` and `b` point.  In the example below, `a` and `b` are assigned to the same string object after `b = a` executes, but since strings can't be modified, there's no risk of unintentional modifications to `b` when assigning another object to a.

   ```
   a = "Strings are immutable, so they cannot be modified."
   b = a
   a = "New string to assign to a.  The first string is still tied to b."
   ```
2. **Shorter Names for Readability**:  Sometimes, it's useful to create shorter names in order to improve the readability of a calculation.

   ```
   # Assign values to variables with descriptive names
   long_variable_name = [1, 2]
   longer_variable_name = [3, 4]
   longest_variable_name = [5, 6]

   # Create dummy variables with shorter names for calculation
   a = long_variable_name
   b = longer_variable_name
   c = longest_variable_name

   # Perform calculation
   result = (a[0] + b[0] + c[0]) / (a[1] + b[1] + c[1])
   ```
3. **Linking Multiple Variables:**  The example below involves two bitter enemies, Angela and Bob.  By default, they hate everything that the other one likes (see last two lines of code).

   ```
   class Person:
       def __init__(self, name):
           self.name = name
           self.favorite_things = []
           self.least_favorite_things = []

   angela = Person("Angela")
   bob = Person("Bob")

   angela.favorite_things = ["piña coladas", "getting caught in the rain"]
   bob.favorite_things = ["yoga", "health food"]

   angela.least_favorite_things = bob.favorite_things
   bob.least_favorite_things = angela.favorite_things
   ```

Comment: Look at your `Person.__init__` method. Look at what the first line in the body does.

Comment: (Really, every variable assignment creates a new reference to an object. Any copying that might happen is a separate operation.)

Comment: There are numerous times when this is desirable. Every time you call a function, there is an implicit assignment of the argument to a function parameter name. E.g., given `def f(x): pass`, a call like `f(a)` performs an implicit assignment of `x = a`. `for i in [a, b, c]: ...` repeatedly makes the assignment `i = a`, `i = b`, `i = c`. I'm not sure listing uses of assignment statements counts as [a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @user2357112, yes that all makes sense, but the line `self.name = name` would fall within the "Immutable Objects" category from my question.  The line `angela = Person("Angela")` is not an assignment case that I'm interested in since `Person("Angela")` has not previously been assigned to another variable, such as in `b = a`, where `a` was previously assigned.

Comment: @chepner, thank you for bringing up implicit assignments.  Those are clearly very useful.  To clarify my question, I am specifically looking for cases where assignment is not necessary but turns out to be helpful (for instance when one already has an object assigned to a variable `a` and decides to assign the same object to another variable `b`).  I would say that is practical, answerable, and unique to software development, and your example of implicit assignments is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for.  Do you have any suggestions to improve my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful as a *label* for something:

```
numbers = [9, 4, 347, 1005, -6, ...]
biggest = numbers[0]
for n in numbers[1:]
    if n > biggest:
        biggest = n
```

At the end of this loop, `biggest` will be the largest value.  Nothing was deepcopied or mutated, only assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's useful when you have to worry about memory efficiency. Sometimes, creating a new reference to an object instead of copying it can save memory, especially when dealing with large objects. Since a new reference does not create a new copy of the object in memory, it avoids the overhead of allocating memory for the copy.
Copying objects can be a time-consuming operation, especially for large or deeply nested objects.
Or, for example, if multiple parts of a program need access to the same data and modifications to that data should be visible to all parts, creating new references instead of copies can be beneficial.